# How to create loop GridView?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp

I have horizontal-oriented UserControl based on `GridView` with images (like carousel).
How can I create infinite horizontal scroll?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition
            Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition
            Width="auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <FontIcon
        Grid.Column="0"
        Glyph="<"/>

    <GridView
        Grid.Column="1"
        Margin="0,10,0,0"/>

    <FontIcon
        Grid.Column="2"
        Glyph=">"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [Carousel](https://github.com/wasteam/waslibs#carousel) control from `AppStudio` controls

Add Library view Nuget Manager

[image]

and use in your `XAML`

```
xmlns:controls="using:AppStudio.Uwp.Controls

<controls:Carousel x:Name="control"
                   ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                   ContentTemplate="{Binding ItemTemplate}"
                   MaxItems="3"
                   AspectRatio="1.5"
                   MinHeight="240"
                   MaxHeight="480"
                   GradientOpacity="0.3"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

put the below code inside the `gridView`

```
 <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Column="0">
```

Comment: Unfortunately this don't help.

Comment: it is not provide a looping effect